# How can i style a button from zero. Get rid of the button theme?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to get rid of the button basic Theme and make the button styleable as an `a` tag. 
I want get rid of all of the ugly gray square in the button and substitute it with nothing as a link.
If you want to see my buttons, visit my website: "http://www.soundbust.com"
Here is my css code:

```
.button {
    padding: 10px 25px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 4px 0px #c8c8c8;
    -moz-box-shadow:    0px 4px 0px #c8c8c8;
    box-shadow:         0px 4px 0px #c8c8c8;    
    border-radius: 6px;
    font-family: 'Questrial', sans-serif;
    font-family: 12px; 
    color:  #e4e4e4; /*#e4e4e4*/
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline;
    margin: 6px 0px;
    background-color: #5a5a5a;              
}

.button:hover {
    background-color: #676767;
    color: #d0d0d0 ;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 4px 0px #bababa;
    -moz-box-shadow:    0px 4px 0px #bababa;
    box-shadow:         0px 4px 0px #bababa;    
}
```

Comment: You want to style the link to look like the buttons?

Answer (score 0):

This could be a great learning experience:

Take a look at [how Bootstrap resets `button`-tags](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#buttons), especially for the "link" type. You can right-click on the link button and choose "Inspect Element..." to see its CSS styles.

It's late now so I'll post some actual code tomorrow if you haven't already figured it out by then :)

Comment: But with bootstrap, it just style the button like they want. I cannot change it to my style.